# Matlab matrix row to row multiplacation of two matrix dimensions not agree

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

I have two matrix A and B for example

**A = [ 1 2 3; 5 4 3; ...]** and B = **[ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6] (row matrix)**

and I want to have this

**A*B = [1*1 2*1 3*1; 5*2 4*2 3*2; ...]** without a loop. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically speaking two matrices can only be multiplied if their dimensions conform; if matrix `A` is `m*n` and matrix `B` is `n*k` then you can form the product `A*B` which will have dimensions `m*k`.  So, from a mathematical standpoint your matrix `A` which is `m*3` can't be post-multiplied by `B` which is `6*1`.  If your matrix `A` is in fact `6*3` then you could form the product `B'*A` which would have dimension `1*3`. Note the use of the transpose operator `'` to transpose `B` from `6*1` to `1*6` here.

Matlab's matrix multiplication (using the `*` operator) conforms to the mathematical requirement that matrices be conformable.  Matlab also offers another matrix multiplication operator, `.*`, which performs element-by-element multiplication, that is it forms the each element `(i,j)` of the result by multiplying `A(i,j)*B(i,j)`.  I see @Thor has already given you one way to do this.

If what you are trying to do is multiply each element in row `i` of `A` by the scalar in row `i` of `B` another approach would be

```
A.*(repmat(B,1,size(A,2)))
```

Alternatively you could use the more efficient, but perhaps slightly less intuitive,

```
bsxfun(@times, A,B);
```

Comment: Aside from backwards compatibility with < R2008, Why not use `bsxfun`? Has a far smaller memory footprint, is multithreaded, faster,...

Comment: Sure, why not.  Post an answer to that effect, SO is supposed to be a collaborative effort, don't hide your light under the bushel of a comment.

Comment: I was merely inquiring whether you had any special reason not to use it. I just edited it into your answer, since you have the best one here.

Comment: No, no special reason.  But I've been using Matlab since before 2008 and some of us old-timers take a while getting used to these darn new-fangled ways ...

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a generic way requires that `A` and `B` have the same number of elements. One way of doing this is to reshape -> multiply -> reshape, e.g.:

```matlab
[x y] = size(A);
AmB   = reshape(A, 1, x*y) .* transpose(B);
AmB   = reshape(AmB, x, y);
```

Comment: I suspect that your answer is wrong since dimensions of B should be [x,1].

Comment: It works with the input given by the OP. Depending on the OPs requirements, the answer might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` has the same number of rows as there are elements in vector `B`

```
AmB = diag(B) * A
```

since what you are requesting is a row scaling.

This expression is elegant but not  efficient. For big tall `A` matrices a loop over the columns `AmB(:,i)  = A(:,i) .* B` should be preferred.